# linux bash/terminal emulator: key "q" not work

Tags: bash, debian, xfce

i am on debian, Xfce desktop env.

When i press the "q" Key, there is no output on the terminal emulator screen/ bash standard output.
The capital "Q" works. In vim the "q" works like every other letter...

How to get the "q" work ?

Comment: What about other programs, such as browser (search or address fields) or `gedit`? If they are OK, what about `cat` (no parameters), which copies input to output until **Ctrl-d**? If these work then probably either `stty` or `bash` has been misconfigured to use **q** instead of a control character: check with `stty -a` and `bind -p`.

Comment: Hi, `bind -p` prints a list: 

"a": self-insert
"b" ...        the line "q": self-insert is missing! How can a add a configration ?

Comment: Type `help bind` into bash for instructions for an immediate change (`bind '"q": self-insert'`). I'm not sure where the self-insert entries come from, so I can't say where you should check for the missing entry. To make the immediate change semi-permanent, add the above `bind` command to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: AFH:   THank you, adding your line to my .bashrc file solves the problem. I wonder how my system get this configuration ...